# Replace array value with more than one values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this,

```
$array = array(
    1,2,3,'4>12','13.1','13.2','14>30'
);
```

I want to find any value with an ">" and replace it with a range().

The result I want is,

```
array(
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, '13.1', '13.2', 14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
);
```

**My understanding:**

if any element of $array has '>' in it,

```
    $separate = explode(">", $that_element);

    $range_array = range($separate[0], $separate[1]); //makes an array of 4 to 12.
```

Now somehow replace '4>12' of with $range_array and get a result like above example.

May be I can find which element has '>' in it using foreach() and rebuild $array again using array_push() and multi level foreach. Looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even do it in a one-liner like this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,'4>12','13.1','13.2','14>30');
print_r(array_reduce(
 $array,
 function($a,$c){return array_merge($a,@range(...array_slice(explode(">","$c>$c"),0,2)));},  
 []
));
```

I avoid any `if` clause by using `range()` on the `array_slice()` array I get from exploding `"$c>$c"` (this will always at least give me a two-element array).

You can find a little demo here: https://rextester.com/DXPTD44420

**Edit:**

OK, if the array can also contain *non-numeric* values the strategy needs to be modified: Now I will check for the existence of the separator sign `>` and will then either merge some cells created by a `range()` call or simply put the non-numeric element into an array and merge that with the original array:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,'4>12','13.1','64+2','14>30');
print_r(array_reduce(
 $array, 
 function($a,$c){return array_merge($a,strpos($c,'>')>0?range(...explode(">",$c)):[$c]);}, 
 []
));
```

See the updated demo here: https://rextester.com/BWBYF59990

Comment: It does take less time to execute than other solutions so if above problem can be solved I will accept this answer.

Comment: Now it works perfectly. The numbers of "x>y" are always numeric so no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to create an empty array  and fill it while loop a source

```
$array = array(
    1,2,3,'4>12','13.1','13.2','14>30'
);

$res = [];

foreach($array as $x) {
    $separate = explode(">", $x);
    if(count($separate) !== 2) {
        // No char '<' in the string or more than 1
        $res[] = $x;
    }
    else {
        $res = array_merge($res, range($separate[0], $separate[1]));
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`range` function will help you with this:

```
$array = array(
    1,2,3,'4>12','13.1','13.2','14>30'
);
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (strpos($item, '>') !== false) {
        $newArray = array_merge($newArray, range(...explode('>', $item)));
    } else {
        $newArray[] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```